# Symbolic integration of logmultinormal distribution

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, probability-or-statistics, distributions

I have been trying to integrate and compute moments of [`LogMultinormalDistribution`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LogMultinormalDistribution.html)in *Mathematica*, but the integrals don't seem to evaluate. Say for the first moment, $\langle x \rangle $

```
Integrate[
 PDF[LogMultinormalDistribution[
  {Subscript[μ, 1], Subscript[μ, 2]},
  {
   {Subscript[σ, 1]^2, Subscript[σ, 1] Subscript[σ, 2] ρ},
   {Subscript[σ, 1] Subscript[σ, 2] ρ, Subscript[σ, 2]^2}
   }
  ]
 , {x, y}
 ]*x
, {x, 0, Infinity}
, {y, 0, Infinity}
]
```

I also tried typing out the PDF,

```
Integrate[(2*Pi*σx*σy Sqrt[1 - ρ^2])^-1*
  Exp[-1/2*(1/(
     1 - ρ^2)) (((Log[x] - μx)/σx)^2 - 
      2*ρ*((Log[x] - μx)/σx)*((
        Log[y] - μy)/σy) + ((
       Log[y] - μy)/σy)^2)]*x, {x, 0, Infinity}, {y, 0, Infinity}]
```

But no luck.

The integrals don't seem to evaluate and either I end up aborting them or the program seems to crash.

In general, I would like compute $\langle x^n y^m \rangle$ for bivariate log normal distribution in mathematica.

**Is there a way to speed up the integrals/evaluate them at all.**

I am running Mathematica 11.3 on Mac OS Mojave if that helps.

Comment: This may not be the problem, but in general you should avoid using [`Subscript`](https://wolfr.am/vxtW3QtE) while defining symbols (variables). `Subscript[x, 1]` is not a symbol, but a composite expression where `Subscript` is an operator without built-in meaning. You expect to do $x_1=2$ but you are actually doing `Set[Subscript[x, 1], 2]` which is to assign a [`DownValues`](https://wolfr.am/vxtQt6LX) to the operator `Subscript` and not an `OwnValues` to an indexed `x` as you may intend. Read how to [properly define indexed variables here](https://wolfr.am/vxtT6JDX)

Comment: BTW, Welcome to Mma.SE. Start by **taking the [tour] now** and learning about [asking](https://wolfr.am/wb2ijD7O) and what's [on-topic](https://wolfr.am/wb2ijD7O). Always [edit] if improvable, show due diligence, give brief context, include **minimal working example** of code and data in **[formatted form](https://goo.gl/ELLhTX)**. By doing all this you help us to help you and likely you will inspire great answers. The site depends on participation, as you receive **give back:** vote and answer questions, keep the site useful, be kind, correct mistakes and share what you have learned.

Comment: Thanks for the link to defining indexed variables. I will keep that in mind. removing the subscripts however, doesn't help either to be honest.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using subscript notation with integration in Mma, provided you don't mix using $x$ and subscript $x$ (say $x_1$) in the same expression.

Comment: @wolfies, I know you think that, you made your point in the Q&A I link, but many people disagree with that, including me. For a new user I think my advice is beneficial, there is nothing to gain and much to loose by using `Subscript` for anything other than display.

Answer (score 10):

Life is easier when one can go straight to the answer without going through the integration.

Given a mean vector and covariance matrix

```
μ = {μ1, μ2};
Σ = {{σ1^2, σ1 σ2 ρ}, {σ1 σ2 ρ, σ2^2}};
```

the moment generating function for a bivariate normal is

```
mgf[t1_, t2_] := Exp[{t1, t2}.μ + {t1, t2}.Σ.{t1, t2}/2]
```

Because the definition of the moment generating function is $E[e^{t_1 X_1+t_2 X_2}]=E[Y_1^{t_1} Y_2^{t_2}]$, then `mgf[t1_, t2_]` is the function that gives the expectation of $Y_1^{t_1} Y_2^{t_2}$.

```
mgf[m, n]
(* E^(m μ1 + n μ2 + 1/2 (m (m σ1^2 + n ρ σ1 σ2) + n (m ρ σ1 σ2 + n σ2^2))) *)
```

You can see that this easily generalizes to more than two dimensions.  Here is a reference with the steps of integration:  [The Lognormal Random Multivariate](https://www.casact.org/pubs/forum/15spforum/Halliwell.pdf)

Comment: There can be no better answer than this.

Comment: @wolfies.  I agree.  But I wish I would have immediately thought of it.  Good thing Google is around.

Comment: Ah this makes a lot of sense. Can't believe I did not think of doing this earlier.

Answer (score 6):

```
Format[μ[n_]] := Subscript[μ, n];
Format[σ[n_]] := Subscript[σ, n]

dist = LogMultinormalDistribution[{μ[1], μ[2]},
   {{σ[1]^2, ρ σ[1] σ[2]}, {ρ σ[1] σ[2], σ[2]^2}}];
```

The [`Moment`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Moment.html)s are built-in for this distribution

```
Moment[dist, {m, n}]
```

[image]

Comment: I guess there is a better answer.

Comment: @JimB Some of those formulas are baked into the code.

Answer (score 4):

For *Mathematica* the integral can be very complicated if all general cases are considered for each parameter. One option to speed and simplify things is to analyze more specific cases using [`Assuming`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Assuming.html).

You would need to decide if these assumptions are valid, and define your own if not, but these seem quite reasonable to me.

```
pdf = Assuming[
 And[x > 0, y > 0, ρ^2 < 1, {σ1, σ2, μ1, μ2} ∈ Reals, σ2 > 0],
 Simplify@PDF[
   LogMultinormalDistribution[
    {μ1, μ2},
    {
     {σ1^2, ρ σ1 σ2},
     {ρ σ1 σ2, σ2^2}
     }
    ]
   , {x, y}]
 ]
```

[image]

Notice I have avoided the use of [`Subscript`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Subscript.html) and used [`Simplify`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Simplify.html) and indentation to make the code more readable.

```
Assuming[
 And[x > 0, y > 0, ρ^2 < 1, {σ1, σ2, μ1, μ2} ∈ Reals, σ2 > 0],
 Integrate[
  pdf
  , {x, 0, Infinity}
  , {y, 0, Infinity}
  ]
 ]

(* 1 *)
```

So the integral is $1$, as expected for a [`PDF`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PDF.html).

```
Assuming[
 And[x > 0, y > 0, ρ^2 < 1, {σ1, σ2, μ1, μ2} ∈ Reals, σ2 > 0],
 Integrate[
  pdf x
  , {x, 0, Infinity}
  , {y, 0, Infinity}
  ]
 ]
```

[image]

```
E^(μ1 + σ1^2/2)
```

Using [`AbsoluteTiming`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AbsoluteTiming.html) the solution took 123 seconds in my computer (Mathematica 12 i7-4770 3.4GHz)

Comment: Hi. thanks this definitely helps. Running absolute timing on my computer however yields 165.78 and 203.667 s for the first and second computation respectively. Is there anyway to speed this up further? I need to repeat this computation several times.

Comment: @jcp see the answer by JimB